# rewrite "href=javascript:" to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<a href="javascript:addProduct('myParam')" id="myLink">add product</a>`
that does

1. adds a new product,
2. displays `a` content as a *link*, and
3. does not navigate away from the page.

**How to rewrite it to jQuery?**

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">add product</a>
and
$("#myLink").click(addProduct('myParam'));
```

would navigate away on click(?!)...

Comment: Also, `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: wait what do you mean ?

Comment: Don't use an anchor for tasks that buttons should be used for.  It breaks accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addProduct(e.target);
});
```

Comment: `e.currentTarget`

Comment: @Serge well, you can see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/target

There is an example even for old IE

Answer (score 3):

Update `addProduct` to take an `event` parameter - then call `event.preventDefault();` to stop the default link action:

```
function addProduct(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //code...
}
```

Your current handler `$("#myLink").click(addProduct('myParam'));` won't work how you think. `addProduct` is going to be executed immediately if you do this, because using `()` at the end of the function actually calls it!

Quick example on passing functions:

```
var x = function() {
    return 3;
}

var y = x; //assigned the function of x
y(); //3
var z = x(); //3
```

If you want to pass a param (other than the default ones) - you'll have to use an anonymous function and then call your function from that:

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e) {
    addProduct(5, e);
});
```

Comment: thanks, what if addProduct already contains a parameter? `<a href="javascript:addProduct(5)"...>` I edited the question...

Comment: CodePen sample https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/JNGWYx?editors=1010

Comment: @Serge - Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. For the equivalent answers prefered the unmodified version of the addProduct(in case used by other functions as well)... thanks again !